# Options Menu Icon is not showing up on tablet

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-optionsmenu

I trying to get my option's menu icon that usually appears in the corner of the screen on my tablet.  It is not there!  I am currently using Android 4.2.2 for development.  Here is the current Java code I'm using:

```
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
   {
      boolean result = super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

      //theMenu = menu; 
      //new MenuInflater(getApplication()).inflate(R.menu.loggermap, menu);

      menu.add(ContextMenu.NONE, MENU_TRACKING, ContextMenu.NONE, R.string.menu_tracking).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_movie).setAlphabeticShortcut('T');
      menu.add(ContextMenu.NONE, MENU_LAYERS, ContextMenu.NONE, R.string.menu_showLayers).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_mapmode).setAlphabeticShortcut('L');
      menu.add(ContextMenu.NONE, MENU_NOTE, ContextMenu.NONE, R.string.menu_insertnote).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_myplaces);

      menu.add(ContextMenu.NONE, MENU_STATS, ContextMenu.NONE, R.string.menu_statistics).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_picture).setAlphabeticShortcut('S');
      menu.add(ContextMenu.NONE, MENU_SHARE, ContextMenu.NONE, R.string.menu_shareTrack).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_share).setAlphabeticShortcut('I');

      menu.add(ContextMenu.NONE, MENU_TRACKLIST, ContextMenu.NONE, R.string.menu_tracklist).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_show_list).setAlphabeticShortcut('P');
      menu.add(ContextMenu.NONE, MENU_SETTINGS, ContextMenu.NONE, R.string.menu_settings).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_preferences).setAlphabeticShortcut('C');

      MenuItem noteMenu = menu.findItem(MENU_NOTE);
      noteMenu.setEnabled(true);

      return result;
      //return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
   }

   /*
    * (non-Javadoc)
    * @see android.app.Activity#onPrepareOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)
    */
   @Override
   public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
   {
      MenuItem noteMenu = menu.findItem(MENU_NOTE);
      noteMenu.setVisible(true);
      //noteMenu.setEnabled(mLoggerServiceManager.isMediaPrepared());
      noteMenu.setEnabled(true);

      MenuItem shareMenu = menu.findItem(MENU_SHARE);
      shareMenu.setVisible(true);
      //shareMenu.setEnabled(mTrackId >= 0);
      shareMenu.setEnabled(true);

      return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
   {
      boolean handled = false;

      Uri trackUri;
      Intent intent;
      switch (item.getItemId())
      {
         case MENU_TRACKING:
            intent = new Intent(this, ControlTracking.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, MENU_TRACKING);
            handled = true;
            break;
         case MENU_LAYERS:
            showDialog(DIALOG_LAYERS);
            handled = true;
            break;
         case MENU_NOTE:
            /*intent = new Intent(this, InsertNote.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, MENU_NOTE);*/
            intent = new Intent(this, WaypointNewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            handled = true;
            break;
         case MENU_SETTINGS:
            intent = new Intent(this, ApplicationPreferenceActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            handled = true;
            break;
         case MENU_TRACKLIST:
            intent = new Intent(this, TrackList.class);
            intent.putExtra(Tracks._ID, this.mTrackId);
            startActivityForResult(intent, MENU_TRACKLIST);
            break;
         case MENU_STATS:
            if (this.mTrackId >= 0)
            {
               intent = new Intent(this, Statistics.class);
               trackUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Tracks.CONTENT_URI, mTrackId);
               intent.setData(trackUri);
               startActivity(intent);
               handled = true;
               break;
            }
            else
            {
               showDialog(DIALOG_NOTRACK);
            }
            handled = true;
            break;
         case MENU_ABOUT:
            intent = new Intent("org.openintents.action.SHOW_ABOUT_DIALOG");
            try
            {
               startActivityForResult(intent, MENU_ABOUT);
            }
            catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
            {
               showDialog(DIALOG_INSTALL_ABOUT);
            }
            break;
         case MENU_SHARE:
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_RUN);
            trackUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Tracks.CONTENT_URI, mTrackId);
            intent.setDataAndType(trackUri, Tracks.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            Bitmap bm = findViewById(R.id.mapScreen).getDrawingCache();
            if (bm != null)
            {
               Uri screenStreamUri = ShareTrack.storeScreenBitmap(bm);
               intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenStreamUri);
            }
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser( intent, getString( R.string.share_track ) ), MENU_SHARE);
            handled = true;
            break;
         case MENU_CONTRIB:
            showDialog(DIALOG_CONTRIB);
         default:
            handled = super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            break;
      }
      return handled;
   }
```

The XML code is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_loggermap_tracking"
    android:alphabeticShortcut="t"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_movie"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/menu_tracking"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_loggermap_layers"
    android:alphabeticShortcut="l"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_mapmode"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/menu_showLayers"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_loggermap_note"
    android:alphabeticShortcut="n"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_myplaces"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/menu_insertnote"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_loggermap_stats"
    android:alphabeticShortcut="s"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_picture"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/menu_statistics"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_loggermap_share"
    android:alphabeticShortcut="i"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/menu_shareTrack"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_loggermap_tracklist"
    android:alphabeticShortcut="p"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_show_list"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView"
    android:title="@string/menu_tracklist"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_loggermap_settings"
    android:alphabeticShortcut="c"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView"
    android:title="@string/menu_settings"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_loggermap_about"
    android:alphabeticShortcut="a"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView"
    android:title="@string/menu_about"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_loggermap_contrib"
    android:alphabeticShortcut="o"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_allfriends"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView"
    android:title="@string/menu_contrib"/>
</menu>
```

I'm assuming it something wrong with my Java code.  What am I doing wrong here?  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify the tablet which you are using. If the tablet has the hardware menu button - the items that did not fit will be there.

I don't see why are you creating the menus in code instead of just inflating

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.loggermap, menu);
    return true;
}
```

And for those items that have an ActionView, add ifRoom too

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
```